# Как создать пустое дочернее окно поверх родительского?

Tags: c++, winapi

При создании дочернего окна, он смещается куда-то вправо, хотя должен перекрывать содержимое, из-за чего это может быть?

```
hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0,
    wc.lpszClassName,
    L"Sublime",
    //WS_POPUP | WS_MINIMIZEBOX,
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    windowX, windowY, windowWidth, windowHeight,
    NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
scroll = CreateWindowEx(0,
    L"child",           
    (PTSTR)NULL,
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL,
    //WS_SYSMENU,
    windowX, windowY, windowWidth, windowHeight,
    hWnd, NULL, hInstance, (PVOID)NULL);
```

Получение координат

```
RECT rect;
GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rect);
printf_s("%d - %d - %d - %d\n", rect.left, rect.right, rect.bottom, rect.top);
GetWindowRect(scroll, &rect);
printf_s("%d - %d - %d - %d\n", rect.left, rect.right, rect.bottom, rect.top);
```

Результат:

**480 - 1440 - 810 - 270**

**968 - 1928 - 1111 - 571**

Comment: Не даю полного ответа, так как сомневаюсь в нём, но видимо ответ кроется в том что ты не учитываешь border size из GetSystemMetrics

Comment: Нуу из серии в WinAPI ты должен помнить не только об outerWidth и outerHeight но ещё и учитывать размер border'ов... А там чёртовых 16 пикселей грязная собака языком слизала.

Comment: Нуу из серии в WinAPI ты должен помнить не только об outerWidth и outerHeight но ещё и учитывать размер border'ов... А там чёртовых 16 пикселей грязная собака языком слизала.

Comment: Дочернее окно позиционируется от родительского, не от рабочего стола.